# L5.6 - Relation on pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relation, laravel-5.6

I've a relation on a **pivot** table; how I can expand It?

For example:

**shops**:

- id
- name

**products**:

- id
- name

**product_shop**:

- product_id
- shop_id
- field_1
- field_2
- field_3
- table_A_id

**table_A**:

- id
- name

The relation Many-to-Many in the `Shops` Model is:

```
class Shops extends Model {
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Products', 'product_shop', 'product_id', 'shop_id')->withPivot(
            'field_1',
            'field_3',
            'field_3',
            'table_A_id'
            )
            ->as('product_shop')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

}

and the query to retrieve all data is:

```
class GetData extends Model {
     public static function getAll() {
         $query = Shops::with(
            'products'
            )->get();
     }
}
```

This return the `product_shop.table_A_id` but I'd like to expand the foreign key  and retrieve `table_A.name`; is there a way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pivot model:

```php
class ProductShopPivot extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot
{
    public function tableA()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(TableA::class);
    }
}

class Shops extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Products', 'product_shop', 'product_id', 'shop_id')
            ->withPivot(
                'field_1',
                'field_3',
                'field_3',
                'table_A_id'
            )
            ->as('product_shop')
            ->withTimestamps()
            ->using(ProductShopPivot::class);
    }
}
```

Then access it like this:

```
$shop->product_shop->tableA->name
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to eager load the `tableA` relation.

Comment: what if, you load it with ->with('pivotmodel.endmodel') because technically you can have the pivot model as a relation ship via a hasMany query. Then you could eager load it.

Comment: That's a good alternative. I meant that there is no way when using the `products` relationship.