# Laravel Many to Many and One to Many Table Model and Controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, laravel-query-builder

Could Some one help me to get figure this out.To start of this is **not a duplicate** of [CRUD and relation between three tables/Models in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56178907/crud-and-relation-between-three-tables-models-in-laravel/56179182#56179182).

There are 2 tables Medication_Patient Pivot Table and Med_Time

Medication_Patient Pivot Table

```
id       medication_id          patient_id
1         1 (MED X)             1 (Patient X)
2         2 (MED y)             1 (Patient X)
3         2 (MED y)             2 (Patient Y)
```

And MEdTime which store time and where the medication was given or not

```
  id        med_patient_id(foreign key)    Day      time      given
   1              1                       Yesterday  0900        1
   2              1                       Today      0900        0
   3              1                       Today      2000        0
   4              2                       Today      0600        1
```

On the Models I have

```
class Medication extends Model {
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function patient()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Patient');
    } }


class Patient extends Model
{
public function medication()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Medication');
    }
}
```

To get the Medication's assign to a Patient

```
 $assignedMeds = $patient->medication()->get();
```

but it doesn't give me the ID of Pivot table which I need to find the Time for medication, So I used **(PLEASE LET ME KNOW IF THERE IS A BETTER WAY TO DO THIS)**

```
//get the id from medication_patient pivot Table 



 $medPatient = DB::table('medication_patient')->select('id')
                ->Where([
                    ['patient_id','=', $patient->id],
                    ['medication_id' ,'=', $medication->id]
                ])->get()->first;
            $medPatientId = $medPatient->id->id;

  //Using Medication_patient_id to find MedTime       
            $assignedMedTimes = MedTime::where('med_patient_id' ,'=' , $medPatientId)->get();

//Filtering the Med Time according to the day 
            $yesterdayMedTimes = $assignedMedTimes->where('day', '=', 'yesterday')->all();
            $todayMedTimes = $assignedMedTimes->where('day', '=', 'today')->all();
            $tomorrowMedTimes = $assignedMedTimes->where('day', '=', 'tomorrow')->all();


            return view('medicationPatient.medTime', compact('patient','medication'),[
                'assignedMedTimes' => $assignedMedTimes,
                'yesterdayMedTimes' => $yesterdayMedTimes,
                'todayMedTimes' => $todayMedTimes,
                'tomorrowMedTimes' => $tomorrowMedTimes,
            ]);
        }
```

But **this only works when I am getting the Time for 1 Medication** (Med X time assigned to Patient X), **how do I setup a loop or relation in query or eloquent to get me all the medication time** (MED X,Y time for Patient X) and pass it into blade.

Sorry of the long post. Would Appreciate if you could show me the Code.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be making it a little harder on yourself having to go directly to the table in that query.  If it were me, I might consider refactoring the database a little bit to make this easier, and to easily take advantage of the Laravel relationships & pivots.

I'm not sure you need to store the data in two separate tables.  I would look to normalize as much as possible and collapse this down to a single table.  You don't seem to need to reiterate yourself in the `Med_Time` table -- the `med_patient` table adds multiple pill's given, so it serves the same purpose as the med_time table (I think).  I suggest just a **medication_patient** table with the pivots:

```
id       medication_id          patient_id         Day      time      given
1         1 (MED X)             1 (Patient X)    Yesterday  0900        1
2         2 (MED y)             1 (Patient X)    Today      0900        0
```

Your relations will be much the same as you have them, but you can draw the pivots right from the model.  This is from the **Patient model**, but your relations are good for both in your question

```
public function medication()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Medication')->withPivot('Day', 'time', 'given');
    }
```

Then, when you need to access the data, just pull the pivot.  Example:

```
$patient->pivot->Day... or $patient->pivot->time
```

Comment: That would definitely make it much easy for me 
 
@Watercayman Wouldn't there be a problem when Performing CRUD on 
`
id       medication_id          patient_id         Day          time        given
1         1 (MED X)             1 (Patient X)    Yesterday    0900        1
2         1 (MED X)             1 (Patient X)     Today         0900        0
`

Comment: sorry, I am unable to get the formatting right,,

Would it still work when a patient has same medication but at multiple times within the same day, Lets say Patient X has Med Y today at 0900 and 2000 and tomorrow at 0900.

Comment: Yes this would work fine.  You are creating records based on *when a pill is given*.  Distinct records form EVERY TIME, regardless of the time or type, so you have all the data you need.  You can pull all the data, and sort based on the pivots later (day, time, etc). (or try to query based on the pivots is fine too using wherePivot etc)  But, this architecture will make your life much easier I think

Comment: i did the database changed and works better, but I was unable to figure how to `$patient->pivot->Day` or something like that to work

Comment: Remember to set up the relationship on both models to have the pivots.  So on the **Medication Model** your `patient()` method will be `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Patient')->withPivot('Day', 'time', 'given');`.  Then, when you query, you can pull the pivots as above.  Take a look at the docs on pivots (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) and then some other SO questions that may help with the basics example: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645723/laravel-eloquent-querying-pivot-table)

Comment: It works, i made a stupid mistake in my code. Didn't do the loop. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like?

```php
public function patient()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Patient')->withPivot(['id']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking you time to answer the question.