# Laravel - Check all instances of relationship for values on pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have a two models that have a many-to-many relationship, with some addtional fields on the pivot table:

```
Shift table:
------------
id - uuid
date - date
address - string
...

Employee table:
---------------
id - uuid
first_name - string
...

shift_employee table:
---------------------
id - integer
shift_id - uuid
employee_id - uuid
hours_worked - integer
...
```

Now, I'm making a Lens in Laravel Nova, and I want to use the query object to check if any of the instances on shift_employee related to a specific shift has a value bigger than 0 for *hours_worked* on the shift_employee table.

My first idea is to somehow use **whereHas** assuming that the Shift model has a relationship *employees*, like this:

```
$query->whereHas('employees' function ($q) {
    $q->where('hours_worked', '>', 0);
});
```

But... this is not working... There are shifts with more than 0 hours_worked for certain employees and this query string is not working for me. How would I do this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50646240/12733135) answer your question?

Comment: Nope not really

Comment: as I understand you are in Shift Resource Model and you want to get only the employees who worked more than 0 hours , right ?
Would you give us the results you get and results u want ?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your models are modeled correctly. If they are, you can access any attribute of an intermediate table with the pivot attribute as below:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    /**
     * The users that belong to the role.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

exemple :

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    echo $role->pivot->created_at;
}
```

In your case, try :

```
$employee = Employee::with('Shift');

foreach($employee as $e){
     $employeeHw[] = $e->shift_employee->where('hours_worked', '>', 0)->get();
}
```

I'm also new to laverel, so I'm not absolutely sure it works, but in theory: P
Usually in these cases I use the query bilder with join which I find easier

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
        ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
        ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
        ->get();
```