# Eloquent Relationship Pivot Table with 3 Model

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, pivot-table, relationships

i'm a little confused, i need to implements a user role according to an trade unions that the user belongs. The user can belongs to a lot of trade unions but his role can be different.

The migrations will be:

```
+-----------+  +-----------+  +---------------+  +-------------------+
|   users   |  |   roles   |  |  tradeunions  |  |  user_role_trade  |
+-----------+  +-----------+  +---------------+  +-------------------+
|   id      |  |   id      |  |    id         |  |     user_id       |
|   name    |  |   name    |  |    name       |  |     role_id       |
+-----------+  +-----------+  +---------------+  |     trade_id      |
                                                 +-------------------+
```

What would be the best way to do it?
I've worked with pivot table with two models, but with three, I'm a bit confused
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/50467990/4848587 help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a UserRoleTrade Model for your pivot table.

Then implement the required functions like the relationship between the User Model and this Model.